# What do you call the part of a roof that opens up?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I know that some houses have these things, and it's not called a window, because there's typically no glass, so I was wondering if there was a name for these things. Maybe there's a generic word you can use for them, but I can't think of a single one.

Comment: Is it a **shutter**?

Comment: maybe? I am not sure.

Comment: We don't really have things like that in Britain, but I'd say it's a type of [***skylight***](http://gosmartbricks.com/different-types-of-skylight-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/)

Comment: I think it would be considered a vent.

Comment: What would **you** call it please? Does a word exist in any language you speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was like a window in the roof I would probably call it a Skylight or Rooflight. This doesn't seem to be the case here.

If the roof slid open I would probably call it a sliding roof, but again, this isn't the case here.

There is probably a word for it that is borrowed from the culture and language where this house originates, but as I don't know that word I would probably just call it a **hinged roof**.

Comment: I am not an expert on the English language and have no formal qualifications in English. I offer my advice only as a native British English speaker. I believe the advice of an untrained English speaker can sometimes be beneficial.